# Es posible realizar este enunciado en java sin usar condicionales?

Tags: java

El enunciado dice: "Calcular el monto a pagar en una cabina de Internet si el costo por hora es de Bs/.1,5 y por cada 5 horas te dan una hora de promoción gratis".

Comment: Edita la pregunta agregando lo que has intentado :D también nos dices en qué parte tienes problemas :D

Comment: Sólo necesito que alguien me diga si es posible y que sentencias o funciones debo usar, hice el código con condicionales, pero no se como hacerlo sin ellas.

Comment: Creo que no me estoy dejando entender, edita la pregunta, agrega el código que has hecho y con ello evitas que la comunidad te de negativos, porque la pregunta tal y como está tiene una baja calidad, aparte puede caer fácilmente para que sea cerrada por: no está claro lo que se pregunta || demasiado amplia || basada en opiniones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí, es posible sin utilizar condicionales, la parte clave está en calcular cuantas veces hay 5 horas en las horas totales, por lo que deberemos usar `Math.floor(horas / 5)` lo cual nos dice qué horas habrá que restar, a la final ese total de horas si lo podremos multiplicar por el precio final.

Acá te muestro mi implementación

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int horas = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    double resultado = (horas - Math.floor(horas / 5)) * 1.5;

    System.out.println("El total a pagar es de: " + resultado + " Bs");
  }
}
```